# Sample a subset of dataframe by group, with sample size equal to another subset of the dataframe

Tags: r, subset, plyr

Here's my hypothetical data frame;

```
location<- as.factor(rep(c("town1","town2","town3","town4","town5"),100))
visited<- as.factor(rbinom(500,1,.4)) #'Yes or No' variable
variable<- rnorm(500,10,2)
id<- 1:500
DF<- data.frame(id,location,visited,variable)
```

I want to create a new data frame where the number of 0's and 1's are equal for each location.  I want to accomplish this by taking a random sample of the 0's for each location (since there are more 0's than 1's).

I found this solution to sample by group;

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF[DF$visited=="0",],.(location),function(x) x[sample(nrow(x),size=5),])
```

I entered '5' for the size argument so the code would run, But I can't figure out how to set the 'size' argument equal to the number of observations where DF$visited==1.

I suspect the answer could be in other questions I've reviewed, but they've been a bit too advanced for me to implement.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to using `ddply` well is to understand that it will:

1. break the original data frame down by groups *into smaller data frames*,
2. then, for each group, it will call the function you give it, whose job it is to *transform* that data frame into a new data frame*
3. and finally, it will stitch all the little transformed data frames back together.

With that in mind, here's an approach that (I think) solves your problem.

```
sampleFunction <- function(df) {
  # Determine whether visited==1 or visited==0 is less common for this location, 
  # and use that count as our sample size.
  n <- min(nrow(df[df$visited=="1",]), nrow(df[df$visited=="0",]))
  # Sample n from the two groups (visited==0 and visited==1).
  ddply(df, .(visited), function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), size=n),])
}

newDF <- ddply(DF,.(location),sampleFunction)

# Just a quick check to make sure we have the equal counts we were looking for.
ddply(newDF, .(location, visited), summarise, N=length(variable))
```

### How it works

The main `ddply` simply breaks `DF` down by location and applies `sampleFunction`, which does the heavy lifting.

`sampleFunction` takes one of the smaller data frames (in your case, one for each location), and samples from it an equal number of `visited==1` and `visited==0`.   How does it do this?  With a *second* call to `ddply`: this time, using `location` to break it down, so we can sample from both the 1's and the 0's.

Notice, too, that we're calculating the sample size for each location based on whichever sub-group (0 or 1) has fewer occurrences, so this solution will work even if there aren't always more 0's than 1's.

Comment: Great solution and explanation.